# How to build & deploy tweaks to Cydia on Jailbroken iOS devices?

Tags: app-store, jailbreak, cydia

How to Create `Cydia` Apps  and  How to deploy the App to the `Cydia App` store?
I am familiar with `Objective-C` , will it be easy to develop `cydia Apps`?
How to install `cydia Apps` to devices?

Answer (score 1):

For those who come to this question in 2021:

Building applications for Cydia are the same as building applications for the App Store. You can use Xcode, make your app, then you just pack it in a `.deb` file.

Probably what the OP wanted to ask is how to make Tweaks. That requires:

- Proper understanding of Objective-C and iOS Frameworks as tweaks do a fair amount of hooking into pre-existing iOS modules to modify their behavior.
- Theos (it's a platform available both on jailbroken devices and on macOS that can compile tweaks).
- A repo.

Cydia (and nowadays Zebra, Sileo, Installer 5, etc) follow the standard Debian Package format. So once you have your compiled `Mach-O` binary for your tweak, you'd need to pack it in a `DEB` file with a `control` file inside describing the tweak.

Here's how a Cydia Tweak DEB control file looks like:

```
Package: com.geosn0w.iSecureOS
Name: iSecureOS
Depends: firmware (>= 11.0)
Version: 1.17
Architecture: iphoneos-arm
Description: An iOS Security Application for Jailbroken units.
Maintainer: GeoSn0w (@FCE365)
Author: GeoSn0w (@FCE365)
Section: Utilities
Icon: https://isecureos.idevicecentral.com/repo/Files/iSecureOS/iSecureOS.png
Depiction: https://isecureos.idevicecentral.com/repo/Files/iSecureOS/iSecureOS.html
SileoDepiction: https://isecureos.idevicecentral.com/repo/sileo/isecureos.json
```

This is a live example from one of my tweaks. All fields are recommended to be populated in the file. These will be parsed by Cydia when the tweak is installed.

Aside from this, your DEBIAN folder can contain a `postinst` file for your tweak. This will run a script or more right after installation. Do this if you need to set up anything on the system, like permissions, folders, resources from the web and whatnot.

An example of `postinst` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo GeoSn0w is preparing the File System... 
chown root:wheel /Applications/iSecureOS.app/iSecureOS
chmod 6755 /Applications/iSecureOS.app/iSecureOS

echo Successfully prepared File System.
```

In this case, I give the tweak proper permissions on the file system, otherwise my tweak wouldn't be able to get root permissions at launch and it needs them.

Not all tweaks need `postinst` scripts.

As for how to build these tweaks, The iPhone Dev Wiki has a great article on how to get started.

Normally, you'd have a `.xm` file for your tweak which looks like this:

```
%hook SBApplicationIcon

-(void)launch{
        UIAlertView* __launchView = [[[UIAlertView alloc] init] autorelease];
        __launchView.title = @"Hello";
        __launchView.message = @"This is an allert";
        [__launchView addButtonWithTitle:@"Dismiss"];
        [__launchView show];
}

%end
```

The `%hook` tells the tweak where to inject itself, `%end` marks the end of the tweak. In between, you can add your methods and your code to override the default behavior of the iOS methods. Please consult the documentation below as the topic is fairly large and complex.

And to answer a common question, no, you cannot write Jailbreak Tweaks in Swift for now. Only in Objective-C.

Documentation:

1. https://iky1e.tumblr.com/post/9561218739/jailbroken-development-starter-pack
2. https://iphonedev.wiki/index.php/Getting_Started#Prototyping_a_tweak
3. https://iphonedev.wiki/index.php/Best_Practices

Answer (score 0):

In order to develop tweaks for Cydia (or just for jailbroken devices in general), you will need to install Theos on either a Mac, Windows, Linux or even the device itself. See [this](https://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Main_Page) page for all details.

Answer (score 0):

Theos was initially “iphone-framework”, a project created to simplify building code at the command line for iOS devices (primarily jailbroken devices). It later underwent significant changes and became Theos, a flexible Make-based build system primarily for jailbreak software development, but also with complete support for building for other supported platforms. Theos runs on, and can build projects for, macOS, iOS, Linux, and Windows (under Cygwin or Windows Subsystem for Linux).

[URL for Installation](https://github.com/theos/theos/wiki/Installation)

Answer (score -1):

First off you will need a jailbroken device duh.
Also you will need to have many ios devices or friends who have them because if you really want to do this and your first cydia is an app that crashes and messes everything up.It may not look good on you as a dev.Secondly no it will be very easy to do this as apple does not want you to do this so it may take you months or years even before your first app is even made.As far as deploying them you will need to install from a source and can't just put them in the "Cydia Appstore".

Comment: No, not necessarily. There is Theos-Jailed which doesn't require a jailbreak. Theos also works on macOS without any jailbreak.